# Option to mark a question silly

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, flags

Here is an example of a really simple question, the answer would come up on a simple search on the INTERNET; but the user has posted the question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/q/43122030/2142994

I would like to know your opinions on having a *Mark as Silly* option for such questions.
I also suggest that for questions marked *silly*, the person asking/answering get no points.

**If a question is *Marked as silly*, it gives the *user permission to delete the question even if its answered*.**

Comment: `I feel such questions are of no great use.` Then *why did you answer it*?

Comment: `I have answered the question and advised the user to delete the question` That's rather mean, considering that you posting an answer, in and of itself, makes the question ineligible for the author to self delete it.

Comment: @Servy The intend was to delete question, but I answered & expect the user to delete the same.

Comment: I'd use the *Mark as Silly* option on this question.

Comment: If the question is a bad question and should be deleted, then you shouldn't be answering it.

Comment: If the question should be deleted why waste your time answering it?

Comment: Deleted my answer if that makes you happy, the point wasn't to answer, it was to ask the user to delete the question.

Comment: @AniMenon If you want to ask the user to delete the question then you do that by posting a comment, not by posting an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is silly

Comment: If a question has been answered, and needs deletion, you can always post a delete-pls request in the [SOCVR chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), so that higher-rep users can see the post and choose to vote to delete it, however, the chat room does not allow delete-pls requests from users who have answered the question.

Comment: *I posted the answer way after someone put up a partial answer.* - Then why not point out to the user who answered that they are potentially trapping the OP with an unsalvageable question. They might have been willing to remove their answer.

Comment: @BSMP Already commented to remove the answer.

Answer (score 36):

We *already* have a button to mark a question as silly, it's right here:

> [image]

That's the button you press when people post silly questions that aren't useful.

Comment: Downvotes - The question just gets closed. I wanted to give the user a chance to remove the question.

Comment: @AniMenon The question being closed doesn't prevent the author from removing it.  In fact, it only makes it that much easier for them to remove it (as it prevents people like you from posting an answer, making the question ineligible for self-deletion).  Downvotes also don't prevent the question from being deleted, and in fact may result in the question becoming eligible for automatic deletion after a little while (assuming people like you don't post answers, making the question ineligible for such cleanup).  The *only* thing preventing the author from deleting it is people answering it.

Comment: I posted the answer way after someone put up a partial answer. Anyhow people like you won't understand it!
I wanted the user to remove the question rather than it going to closed state with an imperfect answer.

Comment: `I posted the answer way after someone put up a partial answer.` Yes, and in the process, you made the question ineligible for deletion.  `Anyhow people like you won't understand it! I wanted to user to remove the question rather than it going to closed state with an imperfect answer.`  No, it's *you* who isn't understanding.  You posting an answer *prevents the author from being able to delete the question*.  The question being closed makes it *easier* for the question to be deleted.  Your actions actively *inhibited* the outcome you wanted to have happen.

Comment: @AniMenon If you think that the question is a bad question, and that it isn't useful, then the appropriate course of action is to downvote, vote to close (if appropriate), and to optionally comment explaining why the question is problematic.  The *worst* thing that you could be doing is posting an answer to such a question.

Comment: I have already down-voted and voted close.

Comment: @AniMenon Great, then you should have stopped there and not answered, or if you felt you had useful information for the author, possibly posted a comment.

Comment: @ Servy the point is even after that the user has no option to delete it with an answer. So I propose a **Mark as silly** option where the user still gets a chance to delete the question.

Comment: @AniMenon So you're proposing an option to prevent people like you from doing what you had done and posting low quality answers to low quality questions, as that inhibits the author from deleting it?  That's...a bit hypocritical.  Anyway, as I mention in my answer, we already have a suitable tool for indicating that a question is silly and not useful, the downvote.  There is also a close vote, to indicate that a question isn't appropriate for the site, both of which make it easier for a question to be deleted.  So we already have such buttons, they're just called close votes and downvotes.